# Capybara find a button by name and test it's css

Tags: capybara

I haven't been able to find a solution for this problem after searching for hours... What I want is simple, to find a button that has a certain value an assert that it has the css disabled. How to do this in capybara???

I tried several combinations without success

```
expect(find_button(I18n.t('dashboard.dashboard'))[:disabled]).to eq "disabled"
expect(find_button(I18n.t('dashboard.dashboard')).to have_css("disabled")).to be_true
```

None of this works? How to do this in capybara?

Edit: example of the html currently tested

```
<div class= "left-navigation">
  <div class="row left-navigation-item">
  <form action="#" class="button_to" method="post">
    <div>
      <input class="left-navigation-button   disabled" value="Dashboard" type="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the kind of HTML you would hope for Capybara to locate.

Comment: Thanks. The input element has no name or id. Are you hoping to locate it by class? I am just confused at what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm trying to locate it by value, in this case value="Dashboard". And then checking if it has the "disabled" css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few ways to do this, but try this one:

```
find_button('Dashboard')['class'].have_content "disabled"
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. However, the has_text method wasn't defined... instead I used the have_content method

Comment: Made the edit to help others. I must have looked at old documentation. Regardless, glad to help. Good luck with your project!